# Largest Triple Products without using sort?

Tags: javascript, array

I implemented the Largest Triple Products algorithm, but I use sort which makes my time complexity O(nlogn). Is there a way to implement it without a temporary sorted array?

The problem:
You're given a list of n integers arr[0..(n-1)]. You must compute a list output[0..(n-1)] such that, for each index i (between 0 and n-1, inclusive), output[i] is equal to the product of the three largest elements out of arr[0..i] (or equal to -1 if i < 2, as arr[0..i] then includes fewer than three elements).
Note that the three largest elements used to form any product may have the same values as one another, but they must be at different indices in arr.

Example:

```
var arr_2 = [2, 4, 7, 1, 5, 3];
var expected_2 = [-1, -1, 56, 56, 140, 140];
```

My solution:

```
function findMaxProduct(arr) {
  // Write your code here
  if(!arr || arr.length === 0)  return [];
  
  let helper = arr.slice();
  helper.sort((a,b)=>a-b);   // THIS IS THE SORT
  
  let ans = [];
  let prod = 1;
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(i < 2) {
      prod *= arr[i];
      ans.push(-1);
    }
    else {
      if(i === 3) {
        prod *= arr[i];
        ans.push(prod);
      } else if(arr[i] < helper[0]) {
        ans.push(prod);
      } else {
        const min = helper.shift();
        prod /= min;
        prod *= arr[i];
        ans.push(prod);
      }
    }
  }
  
  return ans;
}
```

Comment: Can the list of integers include negative numbers?

Comment: Your result for `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` is `[-1, -1, 60, 120, 120]`. Why is that correct?

Comment: Let's assume it can't have negative

Comment: @superbrain looks like it is wrong. Do you have a solution for it?

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 Just the obvious, go left to right and keep track of the largest three values seen so far. And I don't do javascript.

Comment: @superbrain You're on code review... The questions posted here are almost always about the non-obvious way someone solved a problem. Telling someone to "just do the obvious" without any code and/or example isn't helping; it's patronising and at best useless.

Comment: @Maanlamp I fail to see how *"go left to right and keep track of the largest three values seen so far"* isn't helping, and how three people marking my comment as useful means it's useless.

Comment: @superbrain It's useless because, if I understand OP's code, that's what he has done. Except his way of what you call obvious is apparently _not_ obvious. A useful answer (an actual answer below) would be the few lines that make up your solution -- but you don't do javascript so why even bother... That's like being a rocket scientist and telling an aerospace engineer how to build a plane. Also I fail to see how those upvotes say anything other than that some people agree with the solution being obvious -- which makes their upvotes useless too. Glad you all think it's obvious... now what?

Comment: @Maanlamp So you don't understand the OP's code or don't understand what I'm saying. It's not the same.

Comment: @superbrain The `for` loop in OP's code that _goes from left to right_ (or 0 to n, because there's no left/right heading in iteration) and _keeps track of the largest three values_ disproves the first part of what you're saying. I do understand what you've said; I just strongly disagree -- if that wasn't obvious (there's irony in there somewhere). You can both understand and disagree.

Comment: @Maanlamp Where exactly do you think the OP keeps track of the largest three values? You remember their code doesn't even work, right? Plus they're sorting the entire array, which mine doesn't, and which this question is all about.